# Problem with a derivative inside an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I am having some issues solving for the derivative of
$$\int_0^1 q^{\alpha} e^{tq} dq$$
with respect to $t$ when $t > 0$. I tried to perform a direct method of computing:
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow t_0} \frac{\int_0^1 q^{\alpha} e^{tq} dq
- \int_0^1 q^{\alpha} e^{t_0 q} dq}{t - t_0}$$
$$= \lim_{t \rightarrow t_0} \frac{ \int_0^1 q^{\alpha} (e^tq - e^{t_0q}) dq}{t-t_0}.$$

However, I am stuck on how to solve this limit. How should I proceed?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ a positive integer?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the partial derivative of the integrand with respect to $t$. This is justified by Leibniz integral rule, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule . This gives,
$\frac{d}{dt}\int\limits_{0}^1q^\alpha e^{tq}dq=\int\limits_{0}^1 q^{\alpha+1}e^{tq}dq$. Now you can solve this by integrating by parts $\alpha+1$ times, each time choosing $u=q^{\mbox{some power}}$.